# Is there a way to represent edges in graph theory that may only be used once?

Tags: graph-theory

I've been working on taking sentences, converting morphemes into nodes and then having edges connecting the nodes in the different possible syntactically correct orders of a sentence. However, in doing this, the graphs that I create sometimes look like they allow for infinite cycles whereas in fact they do not. For example, I have this graph 
[image]
which would seem to imply that there is a cycle $\sigma(V,I,D)$, which does not exist. Is there a way to indicate that only certain paths are possible and that no cycles exist? What I'm trying to show is that $S$ must be the origination and from $S$ you can go to $V$, $I$, or $D$. Then from each of those you can go to the other two in certain orders. The paths I'm trying to graph are as such
\begin{align}
S \to I \to D \to V \\
S \to I \to V \to D \\
S \to D \to V \to I \\
S \to V \to D \to I
\end{align}
From the included graph all of those paths can be followed, but other non-existent paths can also be followed. Is there a better way to notate these specific paths within the above graph or is there a different methodology that should be used?

Comment: Presumably the paths are always of length 4. And just to clarify, SVID and SDIV are not allowed?

Comment: @bvy The paths are always of length 4. Yes $S\to V\to I\to D$ and $S\to D\to I\to V$ are not allowed.

Comment: The rules suggest a tree, but you probably don't want multiple vertices representing a single morpheme. I don't see a way to model this with a simple digraph. Perhaps some sort of flow network, but it's not my area of expertise.

Comment: @MorganRodgers I'm mapping a french grammatical structure. So you can't for example say "J'ai donné à toi ça" because that doesn't follow grammatical rules whereas "J'ai donné ça à toi" does.